# Select row display to chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Display datatable selected in the chart

(When we click on the check box, the data of the selected row of the table will be displayed in the chart), (The graph page must be empty at the beginning of loading),

To put it more clearly and simply, when I click on each checkbox, it graphs the data in it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
  
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table
      id="table"
      cellpadding="0"
      cellspacing="0"
      data-toggle="table"
      data-filter-control="true"
      data-checkbox-header="false"
      data-click-to-select="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
          <th data-field="id" data-filter-control="input">Id</th>
          <th data-field="sum" data-filter-control="input">Sum</th>
          <th data-field="Avg" data-filter-control="input">Avg</th>
          <th data-field="Max" data-filter-control="input">Max</th>
          <th data-field="Min" data-filter-control="input">Min</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>001</th>
          <td>60.3</td>
          <td>47.5</td>
          <td>23.8</td>
          <td>36.5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>002</th>
          <td>20.3</td>
          <td>47.5</td>
          <td>13.9</td>
          <td>25.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>003</th>
          <td>50.6</td>
          <td>70.2</td>
          <td>65.9</td>
          <td>45.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>004</th>
          <td>20.1</td>
          <td>55.9</td>
          <td>86.4</td>
          <td>75.6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>005</th>
          <td>33.1</td>
          <td>25.9</td>
          <td>46.4</td>
          <td>10.6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </figure>

    <script>
      Highcharts.chart("container", {
        data: {
          table: "table",
        },
        chart: {
          type: "column",
        },
        title: {
          text: "Data extracted from a HTML table in the page",
        },
        yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          title: {
            text: "Units",
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
            return (
              "<b>" +
              this.series.name +
              "</b><br/>" +
              this.point.y +
              " " +
              this.point.name.toLowerCase()
            );
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: @dippas Run the code I put on the page

Comment: yes I've run it, but you didn't attempt anything about the checkboxes

Comment: @dippas Yes, he is right, I tried every code, but I did not get an answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi is this what you were after:

https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/1Lthsjfk/

```js
// For demo purpose only, the Highcharts is throwing warnings !!!
console.warn = () => {};
//

let chart = null;
let Data = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
let Id = 0;
$(function() {
  chart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
    data: {
      table: "table",
    },
    chart: {
      type: "column",
    },
    title: {
      text: "Data extracted from a HTML table in the page",
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: "Units",
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return (
          "<b>" +
          this.series.name +
          "</b><br/>" +
          this.point.y +
          " " +
          this.point.name.toLowerCase()
        );
      },
    },
  });
  $('#table').on('post-body.bs.table', function() {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
      $(this).unbind().off().undelegate().on("click", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        GetTableData($(this).closest("tr"), $(this).is(':checked'))
      });
    })
  })

  chart.series[0].update({
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  })
  chart.series[1].update({
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  })
  chart.series[2].update({
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  })
  chart.series[3].update({
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  })
  chart.series[4].update({
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  })
})


function GetTableData(item, ischecked) {
  Id = parseFloat(item.find('td:eq(1)').text())
  //console.log(Id)
  Data[Id - 1][0] = parseFloat(item.find('td:eq(1)').text())
  Data[Id - 1][1] = parseFloat(item.find('td:eq(2)').text())
  Data[Id - 1][2] = parseFloat(item.find('td:eq(3)').text())
  Data[Id - 1][3] = parseFloat(item.find('td:eq(4)').text())
  Data[Id - 1][4] = parseFloat(item.find('td:eq(5)').text())
  // console.log(Data[Id - 1][0], Data[Id - 1][1],
  //   Data[Id - 1][2], Data[Id - 1][3], Data[Id - 1][4])
  chart.series[0].update({
    data: [Data[0][0], Data[1][0], Data[2][0], Data[3][0], Data[4][0]]
  })
  chart.series[1].update({
    data: [Data[0][1], Data[1][1], Data[2][1], Data[3][1], Data[4][1]]
  })
  chart.series[2].update({
    data: [Data[0][2], Data[1][2], Data[2][2], Data[3][2], Data[4][2]]
  })
  chart.series[3].update({
    data: [Data[0][3], Data[1][3], Data[2][3], Data[3][3], Data[4][3]]
  })
  chart.series[4].update({
    data: [Data[0][4], Data[1][4], Data[2][4], Data[3][4], Data[4][4]]
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" data-toggle="table" data-filter-control="true" data-checkbox-header="false" data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="id" data-filter-control="input">Id</th>
        <th data-field="sum" data-filter-control="input">Sum</th>
        <th data-field="Avg" data-filter-control="input">Avg</th>
        <th data-field="Max" data-filter-control="input">Max</th>
        <th data-field="Min" data-filter-control="input">Min</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>001</th>
        <td>60.3</td>
        <td>47.5</td>
        <td>23.8</td>
        <td>36.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>002</th>
        <td>20.3</td>
        <td>47.5</td>
        <td>13.9</td>
        <td>25.3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>003</th>
        <td>50.6</td>
        <td>70.2</td>
        <td>65.9</td>
        <td>45.3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>004</th>
        <td>20.1</td>
        <td>55.9</td>
        <td>86.4</td>
        <td>75.6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>005</th>
        <td>33.1</td>
        <td>25.9</td>
        <td>46.4</td>
        <td>10.6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </figure>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps